# Windows 7 logo testing

Tags: windows-7, logo-testing

We are using msxml4 as a merge module with our installer. We successfully used it with Windows XP and Vista.
However it generates warning in Windows 7 logo tesing.
Test case 3, succeeds with a warning "File C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\MSXML4.DLL was written to an incorrect location."

any suggestion/idea to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 5):

Switch to the current version (MSXML6 IIRC). MSXML4 has been deprecated.

See [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238/) and [XML Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/09/13/we-are-not-killbit-ing-msxml4.aspx).

Comment: This is really a good to know. However my query is different.

According to test case 3 of Windows 7 logo testing, "Installer should not write directly to the Windows (%WINDIR%) directory and / or to its subdirectories."

According to my knowledge, merge module for msxml4 by default installs itself into %WINDIR%\system32. Now above guideline restricts it.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: See the answer: replace your use of MSXML4 with MSXML6 which is the current version (and may be included in Windows 7 by default). MSXML6 will also work in WinXP and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get an exemption from Microsoft because it is not your software that is causing the problem. We had a number of these when our product was Certified for Vista.